# Create a barcode with upper and lower text

Tags: vb.net, itext

I need to create a barcode with upper and lower text and apply it on all the page of a PDF as the following structure:

```
                               TEXT
                              BARCODE
                               TEXT
```

I'm using the iTextSharp DLL to create the barcode.
My idea is create a JPG image (with the structure) and apply on the PDF.

I have used this code:

```
Bmgraphics.Clear(Drawing.Color.White)
Bmgraphics.DrawString(UpperText, New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), SystemBrushes.WindowText, New Point(0, 0))
Bmgraphics.DrawImage(Barcode, New Point(0, height/ 2))
Bmgraphics.DrawString(LoewText, New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), SystemBrushes.WindowText, New Point(0, height+ 10))
finale.Save("path to save")
```

My problem is about the dimension to give to the Bitmap image.
I need that the longer between barcode, lower text, and upper text give the width of the image.

How can I do?

Comment: Is Bmgraphics a `Graphics` object? If so, you can use `MeasureString` to get the sizes of the two strings, and then `Math.Max` to find the larger of those two widths and Barcode.Width.

Comment: Thanks man, i have found this solution and i have used this one.
it's work fine!

Answer (score 0):

A readable barcode, AFAIK, is always longer than the underlying text.
What am I missing, here?